# Remove icon in unity panel

Tags: 11.10, unity, panel, icons

[image: unity panel icon]

hi, before I use Natty. and I install battery-status like from: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/02/battery-applet-status-ubuntu/ , however, battery-status icon appears also participate in Oneiric (see red circle image), how do I remove it?

also, howto I change font size ang theme color in Oneiric? in Natty usually I use "Appearance".

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. sudo apt-get remove battery-status
2. Type advanced settings at Dash Home search and click on Advanced Settings move to 'Fonts' and set them to your taste.